# How to create new array of nested object form an existing array of object

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

Please help to restructure the object in js.

```
const o = [
  {
    id: 1612,
    Tasks: 'Remuneration sheet mentain.',
    calendar_year: 2021,
    calendar_week_in_year: 45,
    WeekStartDate: '2021-10-31',
    WeekEndDate: '2021-11-06',
    status: 'Done',
  },
  {
    id: 1612,
    Tasks: 'Remuneration sheet mentain.',
    calendar_year: 2021,
    calendar_week_in_year: 46,
    WeekStartDate: '2021-11-28',
    WeekEndDate: '2021-12-04',
    status: 'Done',
  },
  {
    id: 1939,
    Tasks: 'Debtors Reconciliation',
    calendar_year: 2021,
    calendar_week_in_year: 45,
    WeekStartDate: '2021-10-31',
    WeekEndDate: '2021-11-06',
    status: 'Done',
  },
  {
    id: 1939,
    Tasks: 'Debtors Reconciliation',
    calendar_year: 2021,
    calendar_week_in_year: 46,
    WeekStartDate: '2021-11-28',
    WeekEndDate: '2021-12-04',
    status: 'Done',
  },
];
```

```
const required = [
  {
    id: 1612,
    Tasks: 'Remuneration sheet mentain.',
    week: [
      { w_no: 45, calendar_year: 2021, WeekStartDate: '2021-10-31', WeekEndDate: '2021-11-06', status: 'Done' },
      { w_no: 46, calendar_year: 2021, WeekStartDate: '2021-11-28', WeekEndDate: '2021-12-04', status: 'Done' },
    ],
  },
  {
    id: 1939,
    Tasks: 'Debtors Reconciliation',
    week: [
      { w_no: 45, calendar_year: 2021, WeekStartDate: '2021-10-31', WeekEndDate: '2021-11-06', status: 'Done' },
      { w_no: 46, calendar_year: 2021, WeekStartDate: '2021-11-28', WeekEndDate: '2021-12-04', status: 'Done' },
    ],
  },
];
```

Comment: restructure into what format? Also, you need to show your level of understanding by attempting a solution and showing that. Also, please format your code in your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is really just a 'group-by' grouping by `id` and accumulating the relevant properties in an array. Here using [`reduce()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) and [destructuring](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment) to isolate the necessary properties of the iterated objects.

```js
const o = [{ id: 1612, Tasks: 'Remuneration sheet mentain.', calendar_year: 2021, calendar_week_in_year: 45, WeekStartDate: '2021-10-31', WeekEndDate: '2021-11-06', status: 'Done', }, { id: 1612, Tasks: 'Remuneration sheet mentain.', calendar_year: 2021, calendar_week_in_year: 46, WeekStartDate: '2021-11-28', WeekEndDate: '2021-12-04', status: 'Done', }, { id: 1939, Tasks: 'Debtors Reconciliation', calendar_year: 2021, calendar_week_in_year: 45, WeekStartDate: '2021-10-31', WeekEndDate: '2021-11-06', status: 'Done', }, { id: 1939, Tasks: 'Debtors Reconciliation', calendar_year: 2021, calendar_week_in_year: 46, WeekStartDate: '2021-11-28', WeekEndDate: '2021-12-04', status: 'Done', },];

const result = Object.values(
  o.reduce((a, { id, Tasks, ...week }) => {
    (a[id] ??= { id, Tasks, week: [] }).week.push(week);

    return a;
  }, {})
);

console.log(result);
```

The above uses [logical nullish assignment (??=)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Logical_nullish_assignment) if you need to replace it for compatibility reasons you can use an OR short-circuit

```
(a[id] || (a[id] = { id, Tasks, week: [] })).week.push(week);
```

```js
const o = [{ id: 1612, Tasks: 'Remuneration sheet mentain.', calendar_year: 2021, calendar_week_in_year: 45, WeekStartDate: '2021-10-31', WeekEndDate: '2021-11-06', status: 'Done', }, { id: 1612, Tasks: 'Remuneration sheet mentain.', calendar_year: 2021, calendar_week_in_year: 46, WeekStartDate: '2021-11-28', WeekEndDate: '2021-12-04', status: 'Done', }, { id: 1939, Tasks: 'Debtors Reconciliation', calendar_year: 2021, calendar_week_in_year: 45, WeekStartDate: '2021-10-31', WeekEndDate: '2021-11-06', status: 'Done', }, { id: 1939, Tasks: 'Debtors Reconciliation', calendar_year: 2021, calendar_week_in_year: 46, WeekStartDate: '2021-11-28', WeekEndDate: '2021-12-04', status: 'Done', },];

const result = Object.values(
  o.reduce((a, { id, Tasks, ...week }) => {
    (a[id] || (a[id] = { id, Tasks, week: [] })).week.push(week);

    return a;
  }, {})
);

console.log(result);
```

But readility is better than compactness, so you can also write it out in full

```
if (a[id] === undefined) {
  a[id] = { id, Tasks, week: [] };
}
    
a[id].week.push(week);
```

```js
const o = [{ id: 1612, Tasks: 'Remuneration sheet mentain.', calendar_year: 2021, calendar_week_in_year: 45, WeekStartDate: '2021-10-31', WeekEndDate: '2021-11-06', status: 'Done', }, { id: 1612, Tasks: 'Remuneration sheet mentain.', calendar_year: 2021, calendar_week_in_year: 46, WeekStartDate: '2021-11-28', WeekEndDate: '2021-12-04', status: 'Done', }, { id: 1939, Tasks: 'Debtors Reconciliation', calendar_year: 2021, calendar_week_in_year: 45, WeekStartDate: '2021-10-31', WeekEndDate: '2021-11-06', status: 'Done', }, { id: 1939, Tasks: 'Debtors Reconciliation', calendar_year: 2021, calendar_week_in_year: 46, WeekStartDate: '2021-11-28', WeekEndDate: '2021-12-04', status: 'Done', },];

const result = Object.values(
  o.reduce((a, { id, Tasks, ...week }) => {
    if (a[id] === undefined) {
      a[id] = { id, Tasks, week: [] };
    }
    
    a[id].week.push(week);

    return a;
  }, {})
);

console.log(result);
```

Comment: Its working properly. Thank you.

Comment: But can't understand how _??=_ operator works. This operator getting space in between in vs code IDE. How to stop it? Please write.